# Replacing an analog pot with a digi pot in a flying drone controller

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, controller, digital-potentiometer, drone

I'm working on a project at the moment and I'm supposed to change the analog pot on the controller with a digi one. My question is does installing the digi pot changes anything in the controller circuit that requires to fix the interface between the digi pot and the controller or the controller and the drone. Thanks!!

Comment: That depends on what the potentiometer is used for. There's no general answer.

Comment: it's used to controller a drone. basically i'm trying to replace the joystick in the controller with a digital pot to be able to control it using an UNO or a Ras PI

Comment: that doesn't say what the pot is used for. You'll need to give us the schematic containing the pot.

Comment: That's not a sensible way to go about things.  Don't go *through* the original controller, replace it.  Look up the sites where people discuss reprogramming hobby transmitters to operate various toy drones by reverse engineering the protocol to the point where they can operate a suitable RF chip from custom code instead.  At most you'll salvage the RF deck out of the existing transmitter.  Also, external software is probably going to do little but crash or fly away the drone anyway...

Comment: Somewhere between everything and nothing.